# Can I rely on the presence of shell()?

Tags: documentation, d, standard-library, phobos

`std.process` has a nice `shell()` function.

```
import std.process;
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    string Output = shell("ls .");
    writeln("The contents of this directory are:");
    write(Output);
}
```

It is documented in the Phobos source, but not [online](http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_process.html).  This makes me a little hesitant to use it in real code.  Is it experimental and unstable, or are the online docs just falling behind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the documentation generation. You can safely use that function, it's not going away.

I'll file this bug.

Comment: Fixed for the next release (dmd 2.057).